# YUICompressor - compress multiple input to multiple output

Tags: java, yui-compressor

I want to compress multiple input file into multiple output minified files like this :

Input :

```
file1.css
file2.css
file3.css
```

Output:

```
file1-min.css
file2-min.css
file3-min.css
```

I'm trying to achieve that with the following command line :

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar *.css -o $.min.css
```

It is not helping me at all ***> it creates a $.min.cs and not file1-min.css etc...***

You guys have an idea how to achieve that ?

I have search some answer for this into stackoverflow, without success.

Thanks for your help,
Regards.

**Update**

Here is the solution :

```
@echo off
setlocal
echo doing some css min

for %%F in (%cd% *.css) do (
    echo %%~nF

    java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar %%F -o min\%%~nF.min.css
    echo "done"
    )
)
```

Comment: what does "It is not helping me at all" mean? are the files not properly compressed? are there error messages?

Comment: I have just update the post. Thanks for your help Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to loop over your css files and call yuicompressor for each item.

For example, in windows batch

```
FOR /F %G IN ('dir /b C:\yourcssPath\*.css') DO java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar %G -o %G.min.css
```

Comment: Thanks it gives me a very precise idea on how to achieve it :) 
I update the original post with the solution